# Have some syntax error in using sql statment in php

Tags: php

I tried to backup all database in single click using php with sql server. But i got some syntax error in the following statement.

```
$stmt="BACKUP DATABASE" .$row['name']. "TO DISK ='d:\back1\'". $row['name'] . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".bak";
```

Anyone guide me to do this?

Comment: Since we have no idea what your variables contain we can't answer you why this doesn't work. For all we know `row['name']` could be `as'd'awd'a2'dq'2'a2'e*"*"*"""""`. You aren't using spaces on either side though. Please print out `$stmt` after you've made the string and look at that instead.

Comment: Print out `$stmt` after variable substitution and the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a space character between "DATABASE" and "TO DISK":

```
$stmt="BACKUP DATABASE " .$row['name']. " TO DISK ...."
```

Comment: Hi Koby, I want to backup all the db to the specific directory with the same database name and .bak extension at the end . At the mean time can u mention the full statement for my question.

Comment: $stmt="BACKUP DATABASE" .$row['name']. " TO DISK ='d:\back1\'". $row['name'] . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".bak";

Comment: @SaranGaneshan If this solved your question make sure to mark it as accepted. If you're in doubt how this works, please read the short answer here: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)